Number of hydrogen bonds
I'm studying hydrogen bonds in a water system. The commonly accepted parameters are: D-A distance = 3.5 Å and H-D-A angle = 30°. To analyze the hydrogen bonds, I plotted the number of hydrogen bonds per frame using GROMACS, MDAnalysis, and VMD.
For MDAnalysis, I used an angle of 150°, as it represents the D-H-A angle. However, I observed significant discrepancies in the results across these programs, as shown in the plot below:

Given these differences, I am concerned about whether I might be doing something wrong or if there might be an issue with the methodology. Which program's results should I trust? Why is it so different?
Edit: I computed hydrogen bonds with MDAnalysis with this code:
hbonds = HBA(universe=u, d_a_cutoff=3.5, d_h_a_angle_cutoff=150)
hbonds.run(verbose=True)

times = hbonds.times
num_hbonds = hbonds.count_by_time()

And with GROMACS I used this command: gmx hbond -f md.trr -s md.tpr -num numhb.xvg
I read that the average number of hydrogen bonds for each water molecule at 298 K is of 1.77, so GROMACS would be the closest one.

can you provide the exact commands or procedures you used or followed to run the analysis for various software?

Also, the angle definitions in VMD and GROMACS are very different. VMD says the angle of 30 degrees is between Donor (D) - Hydrogen (H) - Acceptor (A), but the gromacs definition is H-D-A. Also, in GROMACS, oxygen is considered an acceptor, and nitrogen is a donor by default.  But in VMD, the oxygen can also act as a donor for some residue types. Did you consider this?

I edited the post with some more information. With VMD I used 3.5 A and 30° as the criteria. As I only have water molecules in the system I didn't consider what you said. I don't really "trust" VMD so I'm more interested in understanding the discrepancy between GROMACS and MDAnalysis.

As mentioned, they use different criteria, specifically the angle used. One must be consistent with whichever they use, it is not necessarily that one is more trustworthy.

Isn't 150° and 3.5 A for MDAnalysis the same as 30° and 3.5 A for GROMACS?

Not quite; draw a triangle using D, H, A as the vertices. If angle(D-H-A) = 150, like in MDA, then the other two angles must sum to 30, so angle(H-D-A) != 30.

Oh you're right! Silly me. Apparently for an angle of 137° the results from MDAnalysis are similar to those from GROMACS. I'll try to modify the MDAnalysis code to account for HDA angles.

If more space for chat is necessary, we do have a GROMACS chatroom here too.
